# How to remove the title from the back button

Tags: navigation, swiftui

After I go to a view, in the back button, next to the chevron image, the navigation bar title is displayed right after it. How can I remove it but maintain the `navigationBarTittle`? I've tried `navigationBarBackButtonHidden` but didn't work.

**UPDATE**

I added:

```
@State private var active: Bool = false
```

and

```
.navigationBarTitle(!active ? "Buscar" : "")
```

When I click the button, the other view looks like as I want, but then everything turns white.

Here's the code:

```
@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")
}

@State private var active: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 18) {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            Text("teste")
                                .frame(height: 180)
                                .frame(width: 330)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            Text("teste")
                                .frame(height: 180)
                                .frame(width: 330)
                                .background(Color.green)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            Text("teste")
                                .frame(height: 180)
                                .frame(width: 330)
                                .background(Color.pink)
                                .cornerRadius(15)

                        }.padding(.horizontal, 12)
                    }
                    ForEach(specialtyList, id: \.type) { specialty in

                        NavigationLink(destination: SearchBar(item: specialty), isActive: self.$active) {
                            VStack(spacing: 18) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(specialty.type).foregroundColor(.white)
                                    specialty.image
                                        .renderingMode(.original)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)

                                }.frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 350, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .frame(height: 100)
                            }

                        }.padding(.horizontal)
                            .background(specialty.color).cornerRadius(45)

                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                }

                .padding(.top)
                .padding(.bottom)
            }

        }.navigationBarTitle(!active ? "Buscar" : "")

    }.accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
}
```

Comment: 1) How is it different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63634075/problems-in-displaying-different-titles-in-navigation-bar)? Asperi's answer should be enough to solve your problems 2) If it's another issue indeed, please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I wasn't able to implement all the functionalities that I had in the previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly in you child view in the navigation bar you want: back button (only arrow, not text) and some navigation title.

What you have currently in your `ContentView` removes its title when you go to the child view:

```
.navigationBarTitle(!active ? "Buscar" : "")
```

and consequently the back button in the child view will have no text.

Which means you possibly don't need this code as well:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")
}
```

Also, you need to specify the navigation bar title in your child view:

```
.navigationBarTitle("detail title")
```

---

Your code is not reproducible but here is a simple demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var active: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: self.$active) {
                    Text("go to...")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(!active ? "Buscar" : "")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("detail view")
            .navigationBarTitle("detail title")
    }
}
```